# How to polly fill in Parcel Bundler?

Tags: webpack, parceljs, babel-polyfill

I am playing around with parcel bundler and I am a bit unsure how to get some of my stuff working.

before in my .babelrc file I had this

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "emotion"
  ]
}
```

but parcel did not like plugin-transform-object-assign & plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread as it said they where duplicates.

When I removed those I got another error what was solved by adding 2 new packages and a plugin to my "plugins"

"@babel/transform-runtime",

```
npm install --save @babel/runtime 
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

now I am getting

```
mobx-state-tree.module.js:2719 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined
    at next (mobx-state-tree.module.js:2719)
    at onFulfilled (mobx-state-tree.module.js:2698)
```

what seems to be an issue with me not having pollyfill

before in my webpack.js I had

```
entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
```

So I am not sure how to achieve this in parcel.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: no, never ended switching to parcel as could not figure out how to convert certain things from webpack to parcel and it started to become too big of a time sink. I probably woulld try a different one if I start a new project as support seems lacking.